# Creating A Dynamic Page with Local TypeScript Data File - Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I'm working on an Event App. I have my event Data stored in my TypeScript file. I'm trying to create a dynamic page for each events once its clicked. I tried creating a [slug].tsx file, but the data is not fetched / getting error.

My codes: 
../data/Events.tsx

```
export const EVENT_DETAILS = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title:
      'test1',
    image: 'event-card-bg',
    industries: ['test', 'test'],
    details: [
      {
        title: '5th - 6th',
        value: 'May, 2022',
        icon: <BiTime style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Event Type',
        value: 'In-Person',
        icon: <BsPeople style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Venue',
        value: 'test Hotel',
        icon: <BiHome style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Location',
        value: 'test location',
        icon: <GoLocation style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title:
      'test',
    image: 'event-card-bg',
    industries: ['test', 'test'],
    details: [
      {
        title: '5th - 6th',
        value: 'May, 2022',
        icon: <BiTime style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Event Type',
        value: 'In-Person',
        icon: <BsPeople style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Venue',
        value: 'test Hotel',
        icon: <BiHome style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
      {
        title: 'Location',
        value: 'test location',
        icon: <GoLocation style={{ width: '24px', height: '24px' }} />,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

../event/EventsList.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
import { EVENT_DETAILS } from '../../data/events';
import { BREAKPOINTS, mediaBreakpointDown } from '../../theme/breakpoints';
import EventCard from './EventCard';

const StyledEventList = styled.section`
  padding: 40px 100px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.whiteSmoke};
  ${mediaBreakpointDown(
    BREAKPOINTS.md,
    css`
      padding: 40px 0;
    `
  )}
`;

const EventList: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <StyledEventList>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {EVENT_DETAILS.map((event) => (
            <Col key={event.id} xs={12} md={6} lg={4} className="my-3">
              <EventCard
                id={event.id}
                title={event.title}
                image={event.image}
                industries={event.industries}
                details={event.details}
              />
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </StyledEventList>
  );
};

export default EventList;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const events = await fetch(EVENT_DETAILS).then(res => res.json());
  console.log(events)
  return {
    props: {
      events
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing got returned on more like it's not compiling and i can't generate my [slug].js file

Comment: change Events.tsx to Events.ts

Comment: `fetch` expects a URL as its first parameter, but you're passing an array of objects to it. You don't need `fetch` at all in this case because the data is local. Pass the `EVENT_DETAILS` directly from `getStaticProps`, e.g. `props: { events: EVENT_DETAILS }`. Also note that `getStaticProps` only works in page components, it won't work in regular components.